# Why most of the heroes have close range physical quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Most of pro-heroes and most of students have some reasonably straight-forward close range physical quirks (explosions, fire/ice, become a rock, anti-gravity and so on).

There are very few heroes who have mental abilities: eraser head and Hitoshi Shinso.
And there are few who has anything long distance (as example Kurogiri).

I believe it's mentioned that it's rare. However, it feels like these kind of abilities should be way-way more effective than close range physical abilities.

It feels like in MFA world, people who has such type of unusual abilities should bubble up to the top (specifically to fight villains). This is especially true, taking into account that gadgets can easily suppliment they physical abilities.

Comment: out of universe reason: it's way to hard to balance long range abilities when they can just stay out of range from the close combat experts. And having 2 long range battlers against each other just makes it devolve into a uninteresting pot shot contest or a beam battle.

Answer (score 3):

This is just my personal opinion:

In the anime, it was only mentioned for Kurogiri that it is rare for someone to have warping abilities.

Besides that, I believe one of the reason that people with unusual ability, such as Eraserhead, are not able to easily bubble to the top is because in order to use their quirks, they have to pay *relatively* higher cost (regardless the nature of the cost) than others, like Eraser head have

> eye issues, which is now affecting his daily life

and also for Shinso, he

> cannot activate his quirk by himself, and at least as of now, he cannot use his quirk freely as he please due to the stress it places on himself

Furthermore, since we know these are unusual quirks, it wouldn't be a surprise if people gang up on them to bring them down, just like

> How the league of villians took down Eraserhead, though there were obviously handicaps that caused him to lose, but the fact remains is that, under certain conditions, he will lose

However, in All Might's case, people have tried to bring him down since forever. A good example is once again, the

> league of villians. IMO, the only reason why he lost is because of his injuries from All For One. If it wasn't, he would definitely beat them - Which implies directly that he is just that overwhelming in terms of "Close range physical attack"

Therefore, they don't become top heroes, though they are definitely way above average.

EDIT:

> The strength that Midoriya exerted even while wearing the support equipment broke, as it cannot withstand the pressure. Which means, at least as far as the science advancement in the show is concern, gadgets still cannot fully overtake physical quirks. However, this is obviously far-stretched, since One For All is literally the strongest quirk. However, in the general case. True, gadgets can easy supplement their physical abilities, but they would have to wield it to use it, and I'm sure it'd be much easier to break their gadgets. (IMO)